# How to solve a partial differential equation with 3 variables?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have just learned the Characteristic Method with 2 variables to solve Partial diferential équations... I would like to know how to solve the next partial diferential equation with 3 variables

$$
\frac{df}{dx}+ Q(z_1)\frac{df}{dz_2}+ Q(z_2)\frac{df}{d z_2}=P(x,z_1,z_2)f
$$
I know that the first thing to do is to write the Lagrange-Charpit équations

Is it something similar to the Lagrange Charpit equation with 2 variables?

Thank you for any advice

Comment: It works exactly the same as the case with 2 variables, just with an extra equation describing the extra variable.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{df}{dx}+ Q(z_1)\frac{df}{dz_1}+ Q(z_2)\frac{df}{d z_2}=P(x,z_1,z_2)f
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{1}= \frac{dz_1}{Q(z_1)}= \frac{dz_2}{Q(z_2)}=\frac{df}{P(x,z_1,z_2)f}
$$